# docker not exposing the port with network host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a docker container listening on port 5555, the image is built with `EXPOSE 5555` in Dockerfile and I am running the container as below

```
$ docker run -d --name controler -p 5555:5555  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net=host  my_image:latest
```

The container starts fine but the ports are not exposed, running docker port returns an error message

```
$ docker port controler 5555
Error: No public port '5555/tcp' published for controler
```

If I run the container without `--net=host` , the ports are exposed and I can access the container.

Any idea or hints on what is really happening here is appreciated.

> Note: I am using the latest docker for mac beta Version 1.12.0-beta21
>   (build: 11019) on my mac running el capitan

Comment: possibly because of the `--net=host` option. See, 'host': use the Docker host network stack. Note: the host mode gives the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure.

Comment: I also came across such problems , when I connected container to host network publishing don't work.
When I connected it with bridge network publishing works..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### `--net=host` option

This option bind the virtual NIC of the container to the host physical NIC (by giving full access to local system services such as D-bus).

When this option is used every program that request a network socket will be granted one by the host from the physical NIC. Your service will then be using the `5555` port as expected.

#### `-p 5555:5555` option

This option bind (through `iptable`-like mechanism) the network socket `containter-ip:5555` to the network socket `host-ip:5555`.

---

#### In other words

It seems, IMHO, a bit illogical to use them both. If the needs is to publish the containerized service to the socket `host-ip:5555` then the cleanest way is to **only** use the `-p 5555:5555` option.

Comment: and what if I run with docker-compose? I tried remove the ports with no lack :-(

Answer (score -1):

add your ip in jdbc url `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://12.45.67.12:5432/postgres`

add this conf in your `pg_hba.conf` file `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

This conf is working for me